# MySQL DAYNAME wise data retrieving for different timezone

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am working in an application where we storing doctor appointments schedule weekday basis. For this purpose, we maintaining a schedule table and a calendar table that stored the date. 
Here is the table snapshot of the schedule table
[image]

In our application, when a user selects a date the doctor's appointment list is showing based on that date dayname. Now I am getting date range wise required data of a doctor like the following query where no timezone used.

```
select datefield as date, 
        (select count(id) 
         from appointment_schedules
         where substring(dayname(calendar.datefield),1,3) = appointment_schedules.week_day 
         and user_id=$user_id
        ) 
from calendar  
where datefield between '$start_date' and '$end_date'"
```

Now we implementing timezone wise appointment list where the appointment list will be shown based on user timezone. Since the weekday is fixed in the schedule table, I don't find out the correct way how to retrieve considering timezone. For example, if the user timezone difference is 8 hours from the server then in a certain period user day will ahead or behind from the server. I am stuck on how can I show user timezone day-wise accurate data in a single query.

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) attack. 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
You should consider using [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenated values

Answer (score 1):

Some rough code below for how you can handle it, I haven't tested this but it should give you enough to fix your queries.

PHP:

```
$utc_difference = -12;
$week_day = "SUN";
$prev_week_day = "SAT";
$next_week_day = "MON";
```

MySQL:

```
WHERE 
  (DATE_SUB(start_time, INTERVAL $utc_difference HOUR) < 0 AND  week_day = $prev_week_day)
OR
  (DATE_SUB(start_time, INTERVAL $utc_difference HOUR) > 24 AND  week_day = $next_week_day)
OR 
  (DATE_SUB(start_time, INTERVAL $utc_difference HOUR) > 0 AND DATE_SUB(start_time, INTERVAL $utc_difference HOUR) < 24 AND week_day = $week_day)
```